# KeyError: 'rowCount' for select clients in Reporting API v4

Tags: python

getting this error when running our newly implemented Reporting API v4
It runs successfully for most of our clients, but runs into this error for a select few. Would love some help figuring it out as I'm a little stuck.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "v4analytics.py", line 424, in <module>
main()
File "v4analytics.py", line 420, in main
extract_all(service)
File "v4analytics.py", line 146, in extract_all
for profile_results in run_queries_per_day(service, profile_id, profile_name):
File "v4analytics.py", line 205, in run_queries_per_day
print 'rowCount: %s' % results['reports'][0]['data']['rowCount']
KeyError: 'rowCount'
```

Error is coming from this section of code:

```
def run_queries_per_day(service, profile_id, profile_name):
""" Runs the query for one profile and return the data """
start_date = parse_date(settings.START_DATE)
end_date = parse_date(settings.END_DATE)
date_range = end_date - start_date
for day_delta in range(0, date_range.days + 1):
current_day = start_date + timedelta(day_delta)
print 'Day: %s' % current_day

has_next = True
next_page_token = '0'
while has_next:
# temp fix for 429 RESOURCE_EXHAUSTED AnalyticsDefaultGroupUSER-100s:
time.sleep(settings.WAIT_BETWEEN_REQUESTS_SECONDS)
query = build_query(service,
profile_id,
format_date(current_day),
format_date(current_day),
next_page_token=next_page_token,
)
results = query.execute()

next_page_token = results['reports'][0].get('nextPageToken')
if not next_page_token:
has_next = False

print 'rowCount: %s' % results['reports'][0]['data']['rowCount']
if contains_sampled_data(results):
with open(settings.SAMPLEDDATA_FILE, 'a') as sample_file:
sample_file.write('profile_id: %s\n' % profile_id)
sample_file.write('profile_name: %s\n' % profile_name)
sample_file.write('\n')

yield build_response(results, profile_id, profile_name)
print
```

Thanks for any help

Comment: From the error, I think that the dictionary does not have the `['rowcount']` column.

Comment: if the dictionary didn't have ['rowcount'] why would the script run for most profiles, but fail for others?

Comment: For this profile, it could be possible that the spelling is wrong, something like that, check this error, if it helps http://imgur.com/a/qe3n9

Comment: thanks for your reply, it helped me figure out the error. The profiles that were producing errors are on an updated version of analytics that has a different name for one of the fields!

Comment: you are welcome